# Is it a prank or are we seriously looking for a new CEO?

Tags: discussion, time-travel-mode

[image: Looking for CEO]

I am wondering if Stack Overflow is really getting a new CEO or it's a part of today's prank.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's what you might call an unfortunate coincidence. When I learned of Joel's intention to step aside, I too wondered if it was an elaborate (and not terribly kind) prank on the company. But no. The blog post is entirely in earnest.

But this question *does* explain why various people asked in comments to the announcement whether the idea was from the new CEO. It was not unless that person has access to a time machine. I expect the search will take some time. While the hope is that it will be several months, I would not be surprised if we don't have the position filled next April 1<sup>st</sup>. (If we have someone to announce in March, I'd argue to hold off until after the month ends just to avoid confusion. ;)

Answer (score 22):

No, that is not a prank. The [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/03/28/the-next-ceo-of-stack-overflow/?cb=1) was already posted on March 28th and nothing there mentions April 1st, not even in the form of "three more days and I will officially resign" or "at the beginning of the next month, we'll contact some headhunters". We have all reason to believe this is a serious announcement.

Comment: If the CEO was ousted for disapproving of the April Fool's "joke," I think he showed his wisdom thereby and ought to be reinstated.